# I'm trying to integrate a 3D model viewer into my GUI, but have not found a single library that will allow me to do this easily. Any suggestions?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, graphics, mesh

I've tried with VTK, PCL and Qt (using the [QVTKWidget.h](http://old.compucell3d.org/Documentation/class_q_v_t_k_widget.html)), however, using CMake is incredibly inconvenient, as the second I update any one of the many libraries that my GUI uses, I have to spend at least another day trying to sort out the linker issues. Additionally, a lot of the time, a lot of information is lost from the 3D models using these libraries.

Note: I am focusing on using PLY as it holds color and geometry information in the same file, but any other format that does the same would be fine

I am currently trying to create a Meshlab plugin, but the support for this library is sparse, and I am yet to successfully compile the Meshlab source.

Any input or direction would be really appreciated. If you guys want to know anything more, please do let me know.

If it wasn't clear in the beginning, I am using Qt (C++) to create the GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the QT OpenGL widget and write some OpenGL code to display your model.
PLY textural format is really simple and you can write a parser yourself.

Comment: Wound up using Qt3D and modifying the viewing widget. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Coin3D](https://github.com/coin3d/coin)?  This is a Free implementation of OpenInventor wich was made by SGI back in the day as a C++ wrapper around OpenGL.

As for integration with Qt there is a library called [SoQt](https://github.com/coin3d/soqt) (in the same site).  They also have a newer library called [Quarter](https://github.com/coin3d/quarter) that integrates more like a Qt component.

I've had greatest success with Coin + SoQt + Qt.

Comment: All links you provided are dead.

Comment: @Laszlo I fixed the links.  I still use this stack and I still like it.  Good luck.

Comment: @Laszlo They had to move because that hosting site pulled support for hg rather suddenly. They are at github now. I edited my answer.